# 1 GPIO for 2 LEDs

Tags: mosfet, led, gpio

I'm designing a keypad with backlights and each button has its own indicator LEDs that will be turned on when a button is pressed. While the indicator LED is on, the backlight LED of that button should be turned off. A master switch for the Backlight LEDs is also included. So I came up with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRBhSR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

it would work like a charm but it's using too many MOSFETs on each button and I don't have that many GPIOs to play with (and I think it's wasting GPIOs). Should there be a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Do the buttons have a second set of contacts which could be used to switch between the indicator and the backlight?

Comment: what sort of LEDs and GPIOs are you using that the GPIOs cannot drive the LEDs directly?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, 4 contacts SPST.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні I can drive with 3.3V GPIOs but I would prefer using 5V rail.  Too much current sink on the MCU will cause heating issues? (I have 10 Buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [addressable](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf) LEDs, then you would need only one GPIO for an arbitrary number of LEDs (and you'd get RGB for both backlight and indicator to boot) and zero MOSFETs.

[image]

Otherwise, one or more shift-registers such as 74HC595 is/are one inexpensive way to multiply the number of GPIO. Another way is to use an I2C expander chip. If you chose to use the [74HC595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc595.pdf) and drive the LEDs directly, it has an OE pin that could be used to simultaneously disable all (up to) 8 LEDs connected to that chip.

Comment: I ended up using a GPIO Expander for the job. Not that much of a cost compared to a bunch of Mosfets tho.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to eliminate the MOSFETs that are being used as inverters, as the others are already inverting. Eliminate M5 and R7 and connect the gate of M4 to the drain of M3 for example.

As for the number of GPIOs, each will do two states, so you can have two LEDs each. To get more you would need to use more than two voltage levels for each GPIO (with a circuit at the LEDs to detect and act on these levels) which may not be possible, or use some type of serial addressing such as a shift register.

There's also a system for driving multiple LEDs from a few GPIO pins called [Charlieplexing](http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch04.html), you might look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any fewer inputs...you have 6 possible states, LED on, backlight on, and both off for each button, so 3 bits is your minimum control without losing flexibility.

You can simplify the backlight-on/off scheme a little, but with the same number of FETs.  Depending on your constraints, there's a few more possibilities.  For instance, if your GPIOs are 5V (or 5V tolerant) you can shake the inverters and use P-channel FETs for the backlight.  If your GPIOs are capable of driving the LED directly, you can run the non-backlight LEDs directly.  Wrapping them all in:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9tfRb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: But if the keypad has 10+ buttons then the Backlight_GPIO will need to drive at least 10+ Nfets.... viable design?

Comment: Not really...you can use one FET if they're all on or off at the same time.  See modified schematic.

Answer (score 0):

drive the activity LEDS from a shift register like 74HCT595, drive the backlight from the other polarity of the outputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsS35b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

drive act1 and act2 from a GPIO or from a shift register to light the upper activity LEDS,  M1 gate to 3.3V to turn on the lower backlight leds where the activity leds are dark  100 ohms may be a bit low for comfortable brightness perhaps try 1K or 330